# maintain same gap between text, textfield & button

Tags: html, css

visit  [link1](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-battle-station-multicolor.html)

search for "check" using CTRL + F, than you can see :

[image]

I wanted to display like this as [link2](http://www.flipkart.com/peacock-basic-architect/p/itmdzdt44rzemzjf?pid=BLCDCYYHKPY9UVMG&ref=L%3A-2686337306475674626&srno=p_1&query=peacock+block+toys&otracker=from-search)

[image]

I need 4 changes as below.

1)i want to change the font-size & font-family of "check availabilty at" text.

2)gap between text, textfield & button should be same.

3)when we enter numbers in textfield, it should show bit space in begining as in link 2

4)Hide the empty gap between below and above block.

```
.shipping-estimation-form {float: left;margin: 0 auto;padding: 0;width: 50%;}
.check_delivery .actions {float: left;width: 25%;}
.check_delivery .f-right {margin-left: 0 !important;}
.check_delivery .f-right, .right {float: left !important;}
.check_delivery .button > span {background: #565656 none repeat scroll 0 0; width: 100% !important;}
.check_delivery .button span {padding: 3px;text-transform: capitalize !important;}
.check_delivery .item.last.odd { padding: 0;}
.check_delivery .block-subtitle {float: left;margin-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px;  width: 21%; font-size:12px; position:relative;left:50px;}
.check_delivery #estimate_postcode {margin: 0 auto !important;padding: 0 !important;width: 50% !important; position:relative; left:100px;}
.check_delivery .search {margin: 0 auto !important; width: 100%;}

.check1 {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.ikon {
    position: relative;
    top:50px;
}
```

Comment: These are all basic css styles you require. The css you've attached seems largely irrelevant to your question. Try create a minimal example if you want help. What part is giving you trouble because at present it looks like an "I don't know css" question.

Comment: i am not much familiar with css, please check 4 problems in question.

Comment: 1st part is giving more problem.

Comment: What have you tried ? Because what you requested seems easy enough, even with some googling..

Comment: @Pogrindis yes, i tried giving more values to font-size. but its going to next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace below css

```
.check_delivery .block-subtitle {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  font-family: Museo,Helvetica,arial,san-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  width: 27%;
}

.shipping-estimation-form {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 30%;
}

.check_delivery #estimate_postcode {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  margin-left: 10px !important;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px !important;
  width: 70% !important;
}
```

Comment: peRFect, this is what i needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
.check_delivery .block-subtitle {
float: left;
margin-top: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
width: 21%;
font-size: 12px; // change size
position: relative;
left: 50px;
font-family: fantasy or (any font family);
}

.check_delivery #estimate_postcode {
margin: 0 auto !important;
padding: 0 !important;
width: 50% !important;
position: relative;
left: 60px; // change it
}
```

About the check button, it is not made properly. Make it a submit button and apply margins

Comment: can you please give code to increase "check delivery availabilty" font-size

Comment: when  i chnaged to more, its displaying in 2 lines.

Comment: .check_delivery .block-subtitle {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    /* width: 21%; */
    font-size: 15px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
}

Comment: please give me code for changing design of "button".

Comment: do it yourself! dont make span. Just design a
    <button type="submit">Name</button>

Comment: i tried like this : `<button style ="font-size:11px; padding:5px;">
   <?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('CHECK') ?></button>
   </button>` but its affecting functionality of that "check" button.

Comment: when we enter numbers in textfield, it should show bit space in begining as in link 2, can you give code for this ?

Comment: /* padding: 0 !important; */   remove this padding

Comment: i removed it, pls check

Answer (score 1):

If you want block to react like text, try to use "display : inline-block".
To set the distance between words (and blocks if they're inline-block), try to use "word-spacing: 10px"

Comment: i tried `display : inline-block` but it didt worked, still "Check Availabilty at" is displaying in 2 lines.